# Tabulator column header alignment

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator, how can I make the horizontal alignment of column headers match the column data, or perhaps manage them individually. A column of centered data looks odd with a left-aligned header.

I am very new at this but I have been through the Tabulator info pages, the bitbucket pages, and searched here. It seems like there might be some way by creating some formatter functions but that seems very obscure for such a basic function.

Thanks, Sam.

Comment: Please provide us with what you have achieved so far with your code.

Comment: I have a nice table with data and some columns left-aligned, some centered, and some right-aligned. But all of the column headers have left-aligned text.

Answer (score 6):

there is now an available property for each column:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", headerHozAlign:"right"}, //right align column header title
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
.tabulator-col-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css">

</head>

  <body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

```js
const tabledata1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli ",
    money: "0",
    col: "red",
    dob: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary ",
    money: "0",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine ",
    money: "0",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon ",
    money: "0",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret ",
    money: "0",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];


const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns: [ //Define Table Columns
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      width: 150,
      align: "center"

    },
    {
      title: "money",
      field: "money",
      align: "left",
      formatter: "money",
      align: "center"

    },
    {
      title: "Favourite Color",
      field: "col",
      align: "center"

    },
    {
      title: "Date Of Birth",
      field: "dob",
      sorter: "date",
      align: "center"
    },
  ]
});

const setAlignment = function(index, alignment) {
  $($('.tabulator-col-title')[index - 1]).css("text-align", alignment);

}
```

```css
.tabulator-col-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
  <button onClick="setAlignment(4,'right')">Set Alignment</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for all this. The style `.tabulator-col-title {text-align: center;}` definitely center-aligned the headings. Before I mark it as answered. Is it further possible to specifically align the fourth column say? (I know the column's title,field etc, just not how to reference the css tags to which I would have to apply the style.

Comment: I've been developing all my long life, generally in finance, rarely on the web. Aligning - and also just generally formatting - headers in a table is very far from weird, it is a basic function of a grid and this is the first of many dozens of reporting/grid tools I've ever seen which makes it difficult. Completely hidden in documentation, which on the whole is fairly good. 

I think most people leave the sorting arrows on, and with those on left-alignment looks best. Without them, matching the data alignment looks best.

I'll overcome this minor adversity and write a wrapper class in php

Answer (score 0):

As provided by dota2pro, `.tabulator-col-title {  text-align: center; }` achieves bulk alignment of headers. And the solution provided for specific columns also works.

Answer (score 0):

use the following property in the column definition to center the header individually (e.g. centered):

```
title:'test',
field:'myfield',
titleFormatter: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) 
{cell.getElement().style.textAlign='center'; return ''+cell.getValue()}
```

(tested with Tabulator 4.5)